# ArcGIS Online Web App generates "no results..." error when clicking results?

Tags: arcgis-online

I added a Search Widget in an AGOL Web Map App. The data source is a feature layer (points) contained in a map service in the associated Web Map.  I am searching on a text field containing the names of individuals located in a cemetery (e.g. Zeublon Vance).  When I enter the name and select a name from the dropdown list AGOL returns an error message "No Results Found...".

However, when I hit enter, it zooms to the first result from the dropdown.

I found a couple of threads on the topic but haven't found where where the problem has been solved.

Is this still a known issue?

https://community.esri.com/thread/192585-agol-application-search-widget-generates-no-results-message

Comment: What were the "threads" that you found on this?  If they are Q&As on this site please include a link to them so that potential answerers do not have to try and retrace your steps before deciding whether to try and answer your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, they weren't on this site. They were on geonet. No one seems to have a resolve yet.

Comment: Threads are rarely as easy to follow as Q&As but it would still be useful to link to them.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.